# Conditionally Sending Response in Catch Block

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to figure out the proper way to handle a potential bad Fetch response. If the Fetch response is not okay, I want to immediately send a 500 response and and stop the rest of the code from executing. But if the response is okay, I want to continue the program and send a response at the end. My code *does* seem to work properly at the moment but I get

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client.

I assume this is because program continues after the catch block and tries to send the second response. Again, the code works but this is obviously not the right way to do it. Is there way I can get the program to stop executing after the response in the catch block is sent?

```
app.get('/route', async function(req, res){
   
    try{
        let response = await fetch('https://www.google.com/NonExistantPage')
        if(!response.ok)    
            throw new Error("err")
    }catch{
        res.status(500).end()
    }
    /*
    Program continues if fetch was successful
    */
    res.send("data")
    
})
```

Comment: you can return a respond any time with if else or else if  condition

Comment: Just add `return` in front of `res.status(500).end()` so it  looks like this `return res.status(500).end()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is trying to call the `res.send("data")` even though it sets the response when error occurs inside catch `res.status(500).end()`. Try returning the response to break the execution of the final response once the response headers are set inside catch as shown below

```
app.get('/route', async function(req, res){
   
    try{
        let response = await fetch('https://www.google.com/NonExistantPage')
        if(!response.ok)    
            throw new Error("err")
    }catch{
        return res.status(500).end()
    }
    /*
    Program continues if fetch was successful
    */
    return res.send("data")
    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`try-catch` is async so don't need to set async function. I use this:

```js
app.get('/route',(req, res)=>{        
    try 
    {
        let response = await fetch('https://www.google.com/NonExistantPage')

        if(!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("err")
        }
    }
    catch (err) 
    {
        /* handle errors */
    } 
    finally
    {
        res.status("status code")
        
        // send data and other things ...
        res.send("data")
        return.end()
    }
})
```